# Se puede vincular una consulta de SQL Server con Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, migration

Estoy intentando migrar mi base de datos Access a SQL Server, es decir, las consultas y las tablas. Pero quiero seguir trabajando en Access ya que éste me permite usar formularios a partir de esas tablas y consultas.

Mi pregunta es, si hago la migración de Access a SQL Server con sus tablas y consultas, luego podría vincular esas consultas a Access? Porque con las tablas no hay ningún problema.

Gracias.

Comment: La respuesta es si. Aqui tienes un [enlace a la documentación](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/importar-o-vincular-a-datos-en-una-base-de-datos-de-sql-server-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!